# Angular 5 jasmine form submit not working

Tags: angular, forms, karma-jasmine

Hi I am writing unit test cases in Jasmine. I have one form with submit button. I am trying to write unit case for submitting the form. Below is my html code.

```
  <form *ngIf="formResetToggle" class="form-horizontal" name="tenantEditorForm" #f="ngForm" novalidate (ngSubmit)="f.form.valid ? saveTenant() :(!tenantname.valid && showErrorAlert('Tenant name is required', 'Please enter a name for the tenant'));">
          <div>
                        <label>Tenant Name</label>
                        <div [ngClass]="{'has-success': f.submitted && tenantname.valid, 'has-error' : f.submitted && !tenantname.valid}">
                            <input autofocus type="text" id="tenantname" name="tenantname" placeholder="Enter tenant name" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="tenantEdit.tenantname" #tenantname="ngModel" required />
                            <span *ngIf="f.submitted" class="glyphicon form-control-feedback" [ngClass]="{'glyphicon-ok ':tenantname.valid}"></span>
                            <span *ngIf="f.submitted && !tenantname.valid" class="errorMessage">
                                <i class="abb_icon_16 ui_error_circle1 erroricon"></i> Tenant Name Required!
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" (click)="editorModal.hide()" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add Tenant</button>
                    </div>
  </form>
```

saveTenant will be the method will be called in component when form is submitted.

```
saveTenant{
  //method implementation
}
```

Below is my setup.

```
 beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [
            NgxDatatableModule,
            FormsModule
           ],
            declarations: [
                TenantEditorComponent,
                SearchBoxComponent
            ],
             providers: [
                {
                    provide: LogMessages, useClass: LogMessagesMock
                }
         ]
        }).compileComponents();
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TenantEditorComponent);
```

Below unit test cases I tried so far.

```
 it('Form should be valid', async(() => {
        component.tenantsform.form.controls.tenantname.setValue('volvoaad');
        expect(component.tenantsform.valid).toBeTruthy();
    }));

    it('Form should be invalid', async(() => {
        component.tenantsform.form.controls.tenantname.setValue('');
        expect(component.tenantsform.valid).toBeFalsy();
    }));
```

These unit test cases are giving following same error.

> Failed: Cannot read property 'form' of undefined

After setting up values for forms I am trying to submit form. Can someone help me to find the root cause of the error. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Have you run `detectChanges()` in a `beforeEach` method? Those forms don't exist, before you run it.

Comment: Also, you use `async` in you tests, but you are not doing any async work there, e.g. using `tick()`. So it is unnecessary

Comment: After removing async and adding detectChanges it worked. Now how can i submit the form?

Comment: I tried as below to submit the form. component.tenantsform.form.controls.tenantname.setValue('volvoaad');  component.tenantsform.ngSubmit; but problem is control is not going inside saveTenant() method. can someone correct me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `detectChanges()` in a `beforeEach` so that the form is created before you use it. This is very common with most of angular tests.

To submit the form, just simply click on the submit button. For that use the helper that angular provides:
https://angular.io/guide/testing#click-helper

Also, don't forget to `detechChanges` again and possibly even `tick`, if there are any async stuff happening